# Is there a way to compare four sets of lists and retrieve the exact value?

Tags: python, list

I have a small large problem. Basically, I have some sets of lists that I need to compare and extract the value from it.

```
brand = ["brand_1", "brand_2"]
search_type = [4, 10]

brand_search = ["brand_1", "brand_2","brand_3"]
value_search = ["value1", "value_2","value_3"]
```

I hope that I can explain myself.

I would like to search the `brand_search` to find if there's a match with `brand` then I need to extract exactly the `value_search` so that I can use the `search_type` to retrieve a part of the `value_search`.

I think this is very tricky and sketchy to do. I tried many methods but failed to extract specifically the value_search.

Comment: Do you really have a comma inside `"brand_2,"`?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: this is probably better handled with a dictionary rather than separate lists, would you be open to changing the format or does it need to stay as lists?

Comment: you should also clarify what `searchtype` does, and what your goal output is

Comment: It could be a dictionary. The search type is a list that should have an int value to retrieve part of the value_search.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but I'm guessing this is what you want.

Use `enumerate()` to iterate through `brand_search` along with the indexes. When you find a match, get the corresponding element of `value_search`.

```
for i, item in enumerate(brand_search):
    if item in brand:
        value = value_search[i]
        print(value[search_type[0]:search_type[1]])
```

Comment: This would work if both lists were ordered. Which is not the case. the brand_search might have brands that are not in order or don't even exist in the brand. That's my main problem

Comment: If they're not ordered, how does it find the corresponding elements in the 2 lists? I said the question isn't clear, I made an assumption based on the sample data. Please edit the question and add more details.